# Pandas - head to head score counting

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a tennis data frame and I am trying to get some statistics from the data. I would like to be able to see the head to head score of the players whether they are player 1 or player 2 and also the same score but on each surface. It will have to have a shift(1) as I want to check the score before the game starts

This is currently what I have

| p1_name | p2_name | Surface | p1_win | p2_win |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Murray | Nadal | Hard | 1 | 0 |
| Nadal | Murray | Clay | 1 | 0 |
| Nadal | Murray | Hard | 0 | 1 |
| Murray | Federer | Clay | 1 | 0 |

and this is what I would want with possibly a p1/2 h2h Surface stat

| p1_name | p2_name | Surface | p1_win | p2_win | p1_h2h | p2_h2h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Murray | Nadal | Hard | 1 | 0 | na | na |
| Nadal | Murray | Clay | 1 | 0 | 0% | 100% |
| Nadal | Murray | Hard | 0 | 1 | 50% | 50% |
| Murray | Federer | Clay | 1 | 0 | na | na |

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you add your own attempt and explain what head to head score means in plain english ?

Comment: I haven't attempted it but head to head is the total win percentage against only that other player

Comment: Thinking off the top of my head, if you were to create a second df where you swapped the p1/p2 fields and concatenated it, now you can group by name and surface and sum up the win columns.  You'd read it directly.

Comment: Your summary data is not quite right.  Murray vs Nadal on Hard is 100% for Murray.

Comment: Hi Tim, that h2h stat is for all surfaces. I would like one for all surfaces and then also a surface specific one if possible. Before the third game starts Murray vs Nadal is 1-1 overall games therefore 50%/50%

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be a good a starting place for you.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [ 'Murray', 'Nadal', 'Hard', 1, 0 ],
    [ 'Nadal', 'Murray', 'Clay', 1, 0 ],
    [ 'Nadal', 'Murray', 'Hard', 0, 1 ],
    [ 'Murray', 'Federer', 'Clay', 1, 0 ]
]

df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['p1_name', 'p2_name', 'Surface', 'p1_win', 'p2_win'] )
print(df)
df1 = df.rename(columns={'p1_name':'p2_name','p2_name':'p1_name','p1_win':'p2_win','p2_win':'p1_win'})
print(df1)
df2 = pd.concat( [df, df1] )
print(df2)
df3 = df2.groupby(['p1_name','p2_name','Surface']).sum()
print(df3)
df3['p1_pct'] = df3['p1_win'] / (df3['p1_win']+df3['p2_win'])
df3['p2_pct'] = df3['p2_win'] / (df3['p1_win']+df3['p2_win'])
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
  p1_name  p2_name Surface  p1_win  p2_win
0  Murray    Nadal    Hard       1       0
1   Nadal   Murray    Clay       1       0
2   Nadal   Murray    Hard       0       1
3  Murray  Federer    Clay       1       0
  p2_name  p1_name Surface  p2_win  p1_win
0  Murray    Nadal    Hard       1       0
1   Nadal   Murray    Clay       1       0
2   Nadal   Murray    Hard       0       1
3  Murray  Federer    Clay       1       0
   p1_name  p2_name Surface  p1_win  p2_win
0   Murray    Nadal    Hard       1       0
1    Nadal   Murray    Clay       1       0
2    Nadal   Murray    Hard       0       1
3   Murray  Federer    Clay       1       0
0    Nadal   Murray    Hard       0       1
1   Murray    Nadal    Clay       0       1
2   Murray    Nadal    Hard       1       0
3  Federer   Murray    Clay       0       1
                         p1_win  p2_win
p1_name p2_name Surface                
Federer Murray  Clay          0       1
Murray  Federer Clay          1       0
        Nadal   Clay          0       1
                Hard          2       0
Nadal   Murray  Clay          1       0
                Hard          0       2
                         p1_win  p2_win  p1_pct  p2_pct
p1_name p2_name Surface
Federer Murray  Clay          0       1     0.0     1.0
Murray  Federer Clay          1       0     1.0     0.0
        Nadal   Clay          0       1     0.0     1.0
                Hard          2       0     1.0     0.0
Nadal   Murray  Clay          1       0     1.0     0.0
                Hard          0       2     0.0     1.0
```